# Net::IMAP::Simple get not getting the entire message

Tags: perl, imap

I'm pretty noobish in perl, so maybe I did something stupid.
My issue is that I'm currently using a script to get all the messages contained by an email box through the IMAP protocol, using Net::IMAP::Simple in PERL, but it does not gives me the entire body of the messages.
My entire code looks like:

```
      use strict;
      use Net::IMAP::Simple;
      
       my $imap = Net::IMAP::Simple->new('xxxxxxxxxxxxxx') or die 'Impossible to connect '.$!;
      $imap->login('xxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxx') or die 'Login Error!';
      my $nbmsg = $imap->select('INBOX') or die 'Impossible to reach this folder !';
      print 'You have '.$nbmsg." messages in this folder !\n\n";
      my $index = $imap->list() or die 'Impossible to list these messages !';

    foreach my $msgnum (keys %$index) {
    #if(!$imap->seen($msgnum)) {
          my $msg = $imap->get($msgnum) or die 'Impossible to retrieve this message'.$msgnum.' !';
          print $msg."\n\n";
    #   }
    }
    $imap->quit() or die 'quitting issue !';
```

And everytime that it is retrieving an email, it is giving me the first characters (which in my case are cryptics useless metadata generated by the bot that sending the messages), but not the entire body.

EDIT: Here is the body part displayed in the output:

> Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: BASE64
>
> Q2UgbWVzc2FnZSBhIMOpdMOpIGfDqW7DqXLDqSBhdXRvbWF0aXF1ZW1lbnQgcGFyIGwnaW1wcmlt
> YW50ZSBtdWx0aWZvbmN0aW9ucyBYZXJveCBYRVJPWF83ODMwLgogICBFbXBsYWNlbWVudCBkdSBz
> eXN0w6htZSA6IAogICBBZHJlc3NlIElQIHN5c3TDqG1lIDogMTkyLjE2OC4xLjIwMAogICBBZHJl
> c3NlIE1BQyBzeXN0w6htZSA6IDlDOjkzOjRFOjMzOjM1OkJECiAgIE1vZMOobGUgc3lzdMOobWUg
> OiBYZXJveCBXb3JrQ2VudHJlIDc4MzAKICAgTnVtw6lybyBkZSBzw6lyaWUgc3lzdMOobWUgOiAz
> OTEyNzk4ODk0CgpMJ0Fzc2lzdGFudCBkZSBjb21wdGV1ciBhIGVudm95w6kgbGUgcmVsZXbDqSBz
> dWl2YW50IGF1IHNlcnZldXIgZGUgY29tbXVuaWNhdGlvbiBYZXJveCBTTWFydCBlU29sdXRpb25z
> IGxlICAxNC8xMS8xNiAgIDA5OjI0OiAKICBUaXJhZ2VzIGVuIG5vaXIgOiAxMzIwNwogIFRpcmFn
> ZXMgZW4gY291bGV1ciA6IDkyNjg3CiAgVG91cyBsZXMgdGlyYWdlcyA6IDEwNTg5NA==

It is always ending by this "==" btw, which is making me think that the module is shortening the output.

I looked after some details about it in the CPAN documentation but sadly didn't find anything.

Comment: Please [edit] and include that output. I believe it's not actually part of the message, but the `ref` of the message object returned by `$imap->get`. Those objects do have a string overload to convert them into text, but you're not using it. You'd have to do `print "$msg"` to force it into a string.

Comment: I did it already. But it didn't change anything. 
I'm editing to add the output.

Comment: Looking at the doc I think you don't need to get the `list()`, you can also just basically iterate from `1` to `$nbmsg` in a loop. The number is not an ID or anything, it's just an index. So `foreach my $msgnum ( 1 .. $nbmsg ) { ... }` would work. That would also sort them directly. What you have now returns the keys of `%$index` in random order because hashes in Perl are not sorted, and the implementation details make the order random. Don't rely no the order of what's coming out there, it would be different on a different machine.

Comment: edited, thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Ohh. That is perfectly fine output. It's base64 encoded content. You need to decode it. The `==` are filler characters. They are padding to make the string have the right length. I'll write up an answer.

Comment: Oh ok! 
It's explaining everything. X) Thanks a lot !

Comment: My answer explains steps to help you figure this out. I can't do it for you because I don't have an imap server to play with. If you need additonal help, just comment on my answer.

Comment: FWIW, a valid base64 chunk is 4x characters long excluding whitespace and a few other characters, and it's padded with = characters to make that true. In this case the original content is 3a+1 bytes, which encodes to 4b+2, so there has to be two padding bytes at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your messages are encoded as [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). It's perfectly normal for emails to have that [MIME type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Transfer-Encoding), though not required. You need to decode them. A good way to do that is to use [MIME::Base64](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Base64). Note that the `==` is part of the Base64 string. It's a padding to make the string have the right length.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use MIME::Base64 'decode_base64';

my $decoded_msg = decode_base64($msg_body);
```

However, you need to get the body out of those message objects. The documentation is vague about that, it doesn't say what those objects are, and `get` only returns the raw message.

I suggest you install [Data::Printer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Printer) and use it to dump one of your `$msg` objects. That dump will include the internals of the object (which is likely a hash reference), and all the methods the object has. It's possible this object includes an accessor to get the already decoded content. If that's the case, you don't need to decode yourself. If not, grab the body out and decode it with `decode_base64`.

---

Update: I read [the code](https://metacpan.org/source/JETTERO/Net-IMAP-Simple-1.2207/Simple.pm#L704), and it creates Net::IMAP::Simple::_message objects in the `get` method. There is [a package definition at the top of the code](https://metacpan.org/source/JETTERO/Net-IMAP-Simple-1.2207/Simple.pm#L17). It's a bit complex, but it's obvious. It uses the arrayref of lines as the data structure behind the object, so I was wrong above.

> ```
> q( package Net::IMAP::Simple::_message;
>    use overload fallback=>1, '""' => sub { local $"=""; "@{$_[0]}" };
>    sub new { bless $_[1] })
> ```

And further down:

> ```
> return  wantarray ? @lines : Net::IMAP::Simple::_message->new(\@lines)
> ```

So to get the body, you need to get rid of the header string. Once you've dumped out the object, you should see how many elements at the beginning of the array are the header and the empty line. I assume index `0` is the header line, and index `1` is the empty line. If you don't care about those, you can just throw them away.

This will change the object.

```
shift @$msg; # get rid of header
shift @$msg; # get rid of empty line

my $decoded_msg = decode_base64("$msg");
```

Comment: By the way, regarding this doc part :

"Optionally, a part can be specified in order to fetch a specific portion of a message. This is the raw, encoded body of the message part. The part number is a set of zero or more part specifiers delimited by periods. Every message has at least one part. Specifying a part of '1' returns the raw, encoded body. This is only useful if you know the header information such as encoding."  

the body could be $imap->get($msgnum , '1.1'), I'll try it

Comment: I just read the update, very instructive. I'm not on my computer anymore, but I'll be back on it soon and try everything.

Comment: @amram you should not have accepted the answer yet if you didn't try. Maybe someone else will have a better one, but if it's already accepted they might be discouraged to post it.

Comment: I accept it as answering at my question about why I don't have the content of my messages.

Comment: Well, actually I'd like to retrieve only the body of my email when I receive a lot of headers added to the output that I sent you earlier. I think I will have to use a regex to separate it from the rest of the message. Maybe on the encoding sentence that never changes.

Comment: Anyway, I tried to decode an isolated message with your :

            my $decoded_msg = decode_base64("$msg");

and it worked well.

Comment: @AmramElbaz if there are multiple lines of headers, find the empty one. It's the separator that ends the header and starts the body. In a stringification its `\n\n`, just like in HTTP. Something like `1 while shift @$msg ne "\n";` should do that. It will still shift out the `\n`, but break. What you put on the left is irrelevant.